# Override route helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, overriding

Question has many Comments.

A URL "questions/123" shows a question.

A URL:

> "questions/123#answer-345"

shows a question and highlights an answer. 345 - is id of Answer model, "answer-345" is id attribute of HTML element.

I need to override "answer_path(a)" method to get

> "questions/123#answer-345"

instead of

> "answers/345"

How to do it ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All url and path helper methods accept optional arguments.
What you're looking for is the `anchor` argument:

```
question_path(123, :anchor => "answer-345")
```

It's documented in the [URLHelper#link_to examples](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to).

Using this argument, you should be able to create an `answer_path` helper via:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def answer_path(answer)
    question_path(answer.question, :anchor => "answer-#{answer.id}")
  end

end
```

Comment: No, i do need it. answer_path should actually point to it's Question's path, and also append hash-part.

Comment: Updated the answer with a helper method. Hope that works for you.

Comment: Thanks. Where should this method be located, to have precedence over default answer_path ?

Comment: You should be able to put it inside the `ApplicationHelper` module or any more specific helper module if the method is not needed on every page.

Comment: Here's an [updated link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) for the API documentation

Answer (score 0):

Offering a solution which covers more areas (works not only in views but also in controller/console)

```
module CustomUrlHelper
  def answer_path(answer, options = {})
    options.merge!(anchor: "answer-#{answer.id}")
    question_path(answer.question, options)
  end
end

# Works at Rails 4.2.6, for earliers versions see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31957323/474597
Rails.application.routes.named_routes.url_helpers_module.send(:include, CustomUrlHelper)
```