# Override rails url helper method globally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionpack

I had a route that is used across my app as `foo_path` => `/foo`

Now I'm migrating this route to another app which defines the URL path differently `/deep/path` and also name the `query_paramters` used in the past by `foo_path` controller differently.

I'm looking to override the `foo_path` method so that now it returns `/deep/path` instead of `/foo` when called in view, controllers ... while transforming some query parameters names

I found some answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31957323/2092619) but the method they use seem not to be working anymore on rails **4.2.7** which is the rails version I'm currently using.

How can I override `foo_path` method across the all app so that it returns `/deep/path` instead of `/foo` in **rails 4.2.7** while being able to manipulate `query_parameters` ?

Comment: Do you want to change `foo_path` to point to a completely different application? If so, you can remove it from `routes.rb` and define it in `ApplicationHelper`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to have a named route.

For example, lets say your old path was identified as `foo` and you accessed it as `foot_path`.

Then you can do some thing like this in routes.rb.

```
'/bar', to: 'controller#action', as: :foo
```

That way `foo_path` will now give `/bar`

ref: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers

Comment: I tried to simplify the problem in my question but in reality, I need `foo_path` method to return `/deep/path/` with some transformations in the query parameters name. I'll update my question to reflect that issue better. Thanks !